# Auto back up using python

Tags: python, automation, scripting, backup

I am utilizing the Python code below to take an automated backup of my files.

```
import shutil
import os
def backup_folder(source_folder, backup_folder):
    try:
        # Check if the source folder exists
        if not os.path.exists(source_folder):
            print(f"Error: Source folder '{source_folder}' does not exist.")
            return
        # Create the backup folder if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(backup_folder):
            os.makedirs(backup_folder)
        # Copy contents of source folder to backup folder
        shutil.copytree(source_folder, os.path.join(backup_folder, os.path.basename(source_folder)))
        print(f"Backup completed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
# Example usage
source_folder = '/path/to/source_folder'
backup_folder = '/path/to/backup_folder'
```

However, when I run it, the backup folder is not getting created. I have tried running it as root, but that did not work either. I am not sure what the issue is.
python3 <name.py>

Are there any other considerations that I may have overlooked? In addition, do you have any ideas on how to automate this process? I'm wondering if it would be possible to use crontab or a Jenkins Job.

Comment: If you run the code that you posted, it will indeed do nothing. You define a function `backup_folders` but never call it.

Comment: Thanks, can I use the code below for calling.
```backup_folder(source_folder, backup_folder)```
 Seems yet it does not work, fails with 
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto_backup.py", line 26, in <module>
    backup_folder(source_folder, backup_folder)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable```

Comment: You name your variable identical to your function and that is why python shows the error. Rename either your variable or your function.

Comment: Lemme try this, can I use the variable as below
source_folder = '/var/log/syslog'
target_folder = '/var/log/backup' 
However, this also threw ```Error: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/var/log/syslog``` 
Please advise